# Trigger Issue please advise

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-workbench

I am thinking of having a trigger update a column in a table i'm using to in essence auto update the specified column as select columns are updated/inserted and if null to not consider them in the overall calculations.

I know it should look something like this:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER gpa AFTER INSERT(or update not sure which here)
 ON student_classes FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

        (here is where i start drawing a blank because none of the trigger tutorial
         sites explain how to do something i could do in excel with little problems
         IE figuring an average spanning multiple columns)

    END;
```

Yes I'm aware I would need a delimiter statement before and after for this as well and i need to check to see if the null entries are null or an actual value and not use the nulls for my calculations. If someone has any clue what I could do to make this happen please inform me because I've yet to come across any examples or tutorials that would allow me to do this. Here is the sql code for what i have of this table so far.

```
CREATE TABLE Student_Classes (StudentClassID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,

StudentID INTEGER,

FOREIGN KEY(StudentID) REFERENCES Students(StudentID),

ClassID INTEGER,

StartDate DATE,

Assignment1 NVARCHAR(3),

CONSTRAINT CK_Students_Classes_Assignment1

    Check (Assignment1 <= 100 AND Assignment1 >= 0),
Assignment2 NVARCHAR(3),

CONSTRAINT CK_Students_Classes_Assignment2

    Check (Assignment2 <= 100 AND Assignment2 >= 0),

Assignment3 NVARCHAR(3),
CONSTRAINT CK_Students_Classes_Assignment3

    Check (Assignment3 <= 100 AND Assignment3 >= 0),

Assignment4 NVARCHAR(3),
CONSTRAINT CK_Students_Classes_Assignment4

    Check (Assignment4 <= 100 AND Assignment4 >= 0),

GPA INT(3.2));
```

Comment: can you be more clear if there is a 2nd table involved or not. Too vague. You need to vastly improve this

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Including a data model with sample data always provides clarity.

Comment: Of course if anyone has any extra questions and I'm able to answer them please ask away

Comment: I'm supposed to be taking 4 entries and making a grade point average from them where we are giving the student's first and last name (each in it's own column) the class they are taking or better yet let me post the SQL code as i have it so far:

Comment: Just so everyone knows it's all within this one table no extra tables will be created from this trigger just adding to the existing one.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want  to take four columns in any given row and compute a fifth column for that same row? If that's the case, it could be done with a trigger easily enough, but it would be more efficiently done with a view, IMHO, unless you *require* a trigger for some reason.

Comment: Just a suggestion- do the `NVARCHAR(3)` fields you have contain only integer data? Maybe you need to change the column types?

Comment: Yes I'm needing to take the 4 different assignments as they are entered and have them update the gpa column as they are entered and a view is beyond our level of expertise at this moment though I am not above using information i'm not supposed to be able to for this.

Comment: Yes the nvchar is correct it's meant to be a variable numeric character set from 0 - 100

Comment: Now I've looked at views and what they can do and yes it would certainly do the job if i knew it well enough however what if someone wanted to view the entire row as is shown in the original table? seems redundant to use a view for that when a normal query would work just as well. please feel free to correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: NVARCHAR isn't "numeric," it's "National Language System." It's a legacy type from before Unicode, meant to specify non-Roman alphabets. You should use INT for integral numbers.

Comment: If someone wanted to view the original row plus the GPA column they could simply JOIN the view to the base table, or you could define the view to return the complete base-table row in addition to the GPA column. One nice thing about views is that querying them is just as efficient as querying real tables, but a view does not actually *contain* any data, so it takes up as close to no space as makes no difference. Your focus should be more on efficient ***storage,*** which supports efficient retrieval.

Comment: You say you're not "supposed to" know about views, and yet you **are** "supposed to" know how to write triggers? If this is for a course, I'd say the instructor got the syllabus backwards.

Comment: Yes it's for a course and the instructor isn't teaching us squat. He's just reading directly from his power point slides which any idiot that can read could do. And also yes we aren't supposed to have knowledge of views yet doesn't mean some of us haven't been proactive with our reading of such things ;) I've been learning lots just reading the comments here such as I got NVARCHAR wrong in it's data type so I will do what i can to correct that quickly. You have all been rather helpful and for that I am gratefull

Answer (score 0):

Since this is apparently for coursework, I won't simply hand you the answer, but I will try to give you some helpful hints and pointers.

First, if you're using a trigger to modify columns in the current record, you generally want to do so ***before*** you save the new data to the table.

Second, INSERT and UPDATE row triggers have access to a "pseudorecord" named **NEW** which contains every column in the base table, and contains the field values ***as they will be after*** the triggering operation completes. (UPDATE and DELETE also have the **OLD** pseudorecord which contains the values ***as they were before*** the DML was issued. DELETE has no **NEW** and INSERT has no **OLD** for reasons which should be obvious with a little thought.) You use **NEW** the same way you would a table alias in a SELECT, by referencing the individual columns as `NEW.column1`, `NEW.column2` &c.

Third, a row trigger generally **MUST NOT** perform explicit DML on the table to which it is attached. The trigger ***was invoked by a DML statement,*** and it is the *invoking* statement which will perform the DML once the trigger code completes. You need only take the values from **NEW**, manipulate them as needed, and then place the modified values back into **NEW**.

An example of a simple trigger can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34091833/mysql-triggers-and-sum/34100815#34100815). In that example the column `income` is in the table `family` (the triggering table) while `total_income` is in another table, `student`.

I hope that will get you started, and I'll be happy to clarify any points that need it.

**EDIT:** Per your comment below, about computing the denominator for the average calculation: I'm answering that here because there's more room and better formatting.

Computing the average assignment mark when individual assignments can be `NULL` is possible, though I confess it took me some thought. (Are you sure this is just a school assignment?) This would not be done in `WHERE`, though, but in the column list of the view's `SELECT`. In a trigger it would be done with local variables the same as in any other procedural language.

A `NULL`-safe calculation for the numerator would be

```
(COALESCE(assignment1, 0) + COALESCE(assignment2, 0)
  + COALESCE(assignment3, 0) + COALESCE(assignment4, 0))
```

and for the denominator would be

```
NULLIF(IF(assignment1 IS NULL, 0, 1) + IF(assignment2 IS NULL, 0, 1)
  + IF(assignment3 IS NULL, 0, 1) + IF(assignment4 IS NULL, 0, 1), 0)
```

I wrapped the denominator calculation in `IFNULL` to protect against divide-by-zero, since `x / NULL = NULL`, while `x / 0` is a runtime error.

Comment: Ah ok then I have a couple questions for you could you first give an exmaple of just a generic view? with some details explaining what's what at least a little bit so i can see what it's really doing and 2nd exactly how would this work spanning across multiple columns to get what is in essence an average score? oh and yes this is for course work and my instructor is . . . . yeah he is just being to nice to say what's on my mind about em. Oh for the new that gets created would that be the table name or would it be like table_name.new? just making sure i got the concept right =) and ty

Comment: An example of a view would be `CREATE VIEW avg_scores AS SELECT studentid, ((assignment1 + assignment2 + assignment3+assignment4) / 4) as avg_score FROM student_classes;` You could then get names and avg scores with `SELECT s.name, as.avg_score FROM students s, avg_scores as WHERE s.studentid = as.studentid;`

Comment: I've just added a link to an example of a simple trigger using **OLD** and **NEW**.

Comment: thank you that will go a long way in helping me figuring all this out. So one other question would it also be possible to use a WHERE command like you did to make it so that if any assignment is null (default value atm) it wouldn't use that for the calculation and to get it to count the number of non null values being used for determining the average instead of the base number of 4?

Comment: That actually took me a little thought. I've edited my answer above to include the solution I came up with.

Comment: ah ok i think i get it won't say i'm sure till i see it in proposed action in my own work but thanks this is much appreciated and you can see why i needed to ask for help from people that would actually give advise even examples i could work with =)