# MySQL triggers and SUM()

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have two tables student and family. In student I have column st_income and total_income. In family I have income. Total_income is sum of st_income from student and sum of income from family where family.id_student=student.id_student.

I want to update total_income by trigger and I made this

```
CREATE TRIGGER family_income_update AFTER UPDATE ON `family` 
FOR EACH ROW UPDATE student SET total_income= ((SELECT SUM(income) 
FROM family WHERE family.id_student=student.id_student)+
(SELECT st_income FROM student WHERE student.id_student=NEW.id_student)) 
WHERE student.id_student=NEW.id_student
```

MySQL accepted this trigger, but when I want to update filed income in table family I get this communicate:

## 1093 - You can't specify target table 'student' for update in FROM clause

I don't know how resolve this.

**UPDATE**

I tried this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER family_income_update AFTER UPDATE ON `family` 
FOR EACH ROW 

SET @familyIncome = SELECT SUM(income) FROM family WHERE family.id_student=student.id_student
SET @studentIncome= SELECT st_income FROM student WHERE student.id_student=NEW.id_student
SET @totalIncome=@familyIncome+@studentIncome

UPDATE student SET total_income=@totalIncome WHERE student.id_student=NEW.id_student
```

but I got this answers:

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT SUM(income) FROM family WHERE family.id_student=student.id_student' at line 4

**UPDATE**

I try add to total_income value of st_income. Both column are in the same table. I tried this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `st_income_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `student`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  UPDATE student
    SET total_income = total_income + (NEW.st_income - OLD.st_income)
    WHERE student.id_student = NEW.id_student;
END
```

But it causes error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what's known as the "Mutating Table" problem. What it boils down to is that a row trigger is not allowed to access other rows in the same table because there's no guarantee that rows will be updated in a specific order, among other things.

First off, you really shouldn't be trying to store total_income when you can calculate it easily when needed. That said, I think you can do what you want by doing something like

```
CREATE TRIGGER family_income_update
  AFTER UPDATE ON family
  FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  UPDATE student
    SET total_income = total_income + (NEW.income - OLD.income)
    WHERE student.id_student = NEW.id_student;
END;
```

The idea is to modify `student.total_income` relative to its previous value, since you can only reference `family.income` relative to its previous value.

Comment: I don't know why I got this: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7

Answer (score 0):

try renaming aliasing the student table in select

```
CREATE TRIGGER family_income_update AFTER UPDATE ON `family` 
FOR EACH ROW UPDATE student SET total_income= ((SELECT SUM(income) 
FROM family WHERE family.id_student=student.id_student)+
(SELECT b.st_income FROM student as b WHERE  b.id_student=NEW.id_student)) 
WHERE student.id_student=NEW.id_student
```

Answer (score 0):

how if you use variabel inside trigger that count total income and then use that variabel in update query ?

something like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER family_income_update AFTER UPDATE ON `family` 
FOR EACH ROW 

SET @totalIncome=(SELECT (st.st_income + ifnull(fam.income, 0)) as     total_income
                  FROM student st left join (
                            SELECT id_student, SUM(income) as income
                            FROM family
                            GROUP BY id_student
                        ) fam on fam.id_student = st.id_student
                  WHERE st.id_student = NEW.id_student);

UPDATE student 
SET total_income = @totalIncome 
WHERE student.id_student=NEW.id_student;
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE student SET total_income=@totalIncome WHERE student.id_student=NEW.id_stu' at line 6

Comment: i have edit my answer to change the query to get total income from family and student table and put it in variabel